# How do I transfer input data from one page to another with form table?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, dynamic-tables

I am creating a mock task manager using Bootstrap-4 and Vue.js. I am new to all of this but I have gotten far. The last thing I must do is send the input data from one of my html pages to the other, which has a form table that should be filled out with the input data. I have pasted a Plunker link of my code. I need help in understanding how to send the input data to fill out the table.

Thank you!

http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/J7bfcZVocpWkEkvpRWX7/

Comment: Since you are new to Vue, it is good if you dig into Vuex and understand it is useful to this kind of scenario. Vuex simply is about having a global store where you can put data that is accessible throughout your application and from any component.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Vuex. 
Create a main store then on your first page send your data to store using mutations or actions and in your second page access it using getters.

**Second option**
Create two individual components, render them on one single page and pass your data to the components using props.